# The iOS Challenge- Winners!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Update: Congratulations to the following people for winning the iOS Challenge!

- The prize for the [most viewed question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/37465/11241) goes to jjeaton.
- The prize for the [highest scored question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37684/does-the-iphone-4s-generate-a-spark-or-detectable-electric-signal-of-any-kind-wh) goes to Michiel.
- The prize for the [most viewed question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37119/make-my-icloud-me-com-email-my-primary-apple-id) asked by a TUAW reader goes to MHartley89.
- The prize for the [highest scored question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37066/sharing-files-and-documents-across-computers-and-devices) asked by a TUAW reader goes to Quacker Backer

Take the red pill. Okay? Sounds great!

To enter this contest: Ask questions related to [ios](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) (Apple’s operating system for mobile devices). Anything tagged [ios](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) is eligible for this contest, but make sure you add other tags as well!

Prizes will go to the people who ask 
the **most viewed question** and
the **question with the highest score** (in terms of votes).

If you win, you will have your choice of a 16GB iPod nano (6th Generation) or any Apple accessories of comparable value for your mobile device.

[image]

Dates: The contest begins Monday, January 16th at 10 am and goes until Friday, January 27th at 11:59 pm (EST). Only questions that are asked within that time period will count towards this contest.

For more info, check out the latest Ask Different [blog post](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/the-ios-challenge/).

Take the red pill, **[ask why](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).**

Comment: The [first post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37714/how-can-i-incorporate-latex-into-an-ibook-created-with-ibooks-author), while an excellent question, isn't tagged with [ios]

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. We're still tallying final results. Meta post is updated now.

Comment: This question is closed since the relevant promotion is over and that code inactive.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, awesome! This is really cool. Thanks for the votes! I'll enjoy my new iPod nano! Thanks you guys!