# Could Community♦ not bump questions without accepted answers on meta?

Tags: feature-request

So we've [established](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/should-we-have-posts-on-meta-that-arent-questions-that-can-be-answered) that it's appropriate for meta to contain questions that aren't really answerable. Which suggests that the algorithm whereby Community♦ randomly bumps questions without accepted answers to the top of the list might not be a particularly good idea in meta.

Case in point: podcast #2 was just bumped to the top of meta. Really?
[image]

Comment: I don't know whether this is a bug, a feature request, or a "feature" removal request.

Comment: Feature request, IMO. [Community ♦](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/-1/) is doing it's intended behavior, behavior I don't think it should have on any meta site. (At least not by default. If someone thinks it should be on a meta, that should be their exception, not the rule.)

Comment: Where is the list of what and how http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/-1/ (aka [Community ♦](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/-1/)) does it's tasks? Sometimes I'd ask it to just go calculate the square root of it's user number and come back when it has an answer.

Comment: It just has to use its imagination, @bmike, and the answer's easy.

Comment: Someone downvoted this -- if you just think this isn't a priority, great, but if you have an argument why it's actually desirable to randomly bump unanswered posts on meta, please do respond; I'd love to hear the argument.

Comment: If no one ever answers this, it can be performance art by @community